# Proof variance and sum of random variables

Tags: matrix-equations, covariance, variance

I am trying to prove two statistical formulas and I am having difficulties..

First, I am trying to prove the following:

If we have the random variable:
$Y = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i$

Prove that the variance of $Y$ is:

$$\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \operatorname{cov}(X_i,Y)$$

I later would like to do the same thing with $W$:

If we have the random variable:
$$W = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i Y_i-c_i Z_i$$

Prove that the variance of W is:

$$\operatorname{Var}(W)=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\operatorname{cov}(Y_i,W)-c_i\operatorname{cov}(Z_i,W)$$

Thank you!

Comment: Note that var(Y)=cov(Y,Y) and cov is bilinear.